# How to determine Acid-Base Indicator

Tags: experimental-chemistry

How do we determine which is the best indicator to use when given the initial pH’s of both the acids and bases and the endpoint value of our base?

[image: Acid Bass Titration Experiment]

Comment: The first row in the worksheet is unconventional because it represents a titration of a weak acid with a weak base. The change in pH after reaching the equivalence point will be much smaller than in cases where the titration is with a strong acid or base, but when carefully done, these titrations do yield results ([source](http://article.sapub.org/10.5923.j.jlce.20180604.03.html)).

Comment: I have a poor impression of the question since the pH values are given for the titrant and the analyte. In order to properly judge the *equivalence point* it would be better to know the pKa values of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All acid-base indicators are weak acids or bases themselves. They have a pKa value associated with them. The pH at which they change color "quickly" is

pH of abrupt color change = pKa-1 to pKa+1;

For example phenolphthalein has a pKa of 9.3, so it will quickly change colors in the pH range of 8.3 to 10.3, whichever side your are approaching this range. This is how those numbers are listed for your indicators.

So how do we choose an indicator? The punchline is that your **end-point*** must lie close the pH range of abrupt color change. Take the titration of HCl (in a flask)and NaOH (in a burette). Now you see that pH has reached 7; in order to ensure that there is no trace of acid remaining, you would add a fraction of a drop of a base to the flask; the pH will quickly jump to an alkaline pH because there is no acid anymore. Which indicator would abruptly change color as it sees a slightly excess of base? Phenolphthalein (8.2 to 10.2 as per your text)

You can do the rest using similar logic.

---

*** Finer details:** Your text is wrong in the sense of using the word endpoint. End point in a classical sense means that you have *added a slight excess* (fraction of a drop) to the titration flask. This indicates end of the titration. The correct term in your scanned image should be "equivalence point" where the titration has just been completed (equivalent amounts of base and acids have reacted); so the end point of a strong acid- base titration is *not at pH of 7.0*, it is slightly basic if the base is being added from the burette. Ask your teacher to clarify further.

Comment: You're confused about the terms *end point* and *equivalence point*. The *end point* is the pH which you are trying to reach in the titration, ie when the titration "ends" due to the color change of the indicator. Assuming you're starting with an acidic solution, then the *equivalence point* is when you have added as many moles of base as there were of acid.

Comment: *RE: "For example phenolphthalein has a pKa of 9.3, so it will be useful in changing colors in the pH range of 8.3 to 10.3.* // Not true. When using  phenolphthalein you're looking for the color to appear around 8 or disappear at 8. It is impossible to tell by eye when all the  phenolphthalein has been converted to the colored form. In other words you can't tell the difference between 90% converted and 99% converted by eye.

Comment: Also the pH does not have to be 7 at either the *end point* or the *equivalence point*.

Comment: @ MaxW, regarding equivalence and end point, both of us saying the same thing. The scanned images uses the wrong term. It should be equivalence point. I have further clarified the statement regarding phenolphthalein for the student.

Comment: The moderator removed some comments. // M Farooq - We're not saying the same thing and the OP's scanned image uses the term *end point* correctly. One can only titrate to the *end point* where the indicator color changes.

Comment: The moderator removed comments upon my request including yours. The forums are meant for discussion in a constructive way without denigrating each other. If you don't like someone's response, feel free to write another answer. My opinion is that the way it is written is misleading for students. Showing that the end point pH of NaOH/HCl titration is at a pH of 7.0 is misleading. Yes, the equivalence point pH = 7.0. It is a classical volumetric titration not a potentiometric one. In potentiometric titration we get the equivalence point because it is free from the bias of an indicator.

Comment: Assuming relatively equal concentrations of acid and base, then the *equivalence point* will be half way between the two pKa values, not at pH =7. The pH value of 7 has nothing to do with either the *end point* or the *equivalence point*. // Also as I have repeatedly stated a titration can only be done to the *end point*, not the *equivalence point*. // I can't add another answer, the question has been locked.

Comment: Please look up the definition of equivalence point and end point from any standard analytical chemistry textbook (Vogel's or even Kolthoff are classical ones). Remove this misconception from your mind that equivalence point cannot be located. Potentiometric titrations can do it (in principle). When we use indicators, we locate the end point. Who said that pH at the end point must be 7.0? It could just be a high school boy's misconception which has nothing to do with real life analytical chemistry. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_point